# How to query the data from content type without using content query webpart in SharePoint2010.How can i?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to query the data from content type without using content query webpart. How could I do this?

My scenario is, I have a page layout, from the page layout I have created a page that contains some site columns values. After clicking on the save button I need to update the field in the page library column. How can I query the data in item updating event of the Site Pages Library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ItemUpdating event method is passed an SPItemEventProperties parameter named property.  This object contains information about the item responsible for firing the event handler.  You can access this by calling properties.ListItem[*Fieldname*] or properties.AfterProperties[*fieldname*].

Something to note.  The value of the SPItemEventProperties.BeforeProperties and SPItemEventProperties.AfterProperties as well as the properties of the SPItemEventProperties.ListItem, varies depending on the Event you are overriding and the type of SP List (List or Document Library).  This [chart](http://forums.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4223/) shows these relationships.